# Danjgo Model update_or_create with field pre-processing

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to Danjgo and it maybe a simple thing, but random searching does not seem to have helped. I am using [Django Ninja API](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-and-pydantic/?ref=morioh.com) example, but I think this is not about Ninja.

In a simple model e.g.

models.py

```
class Person (models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

schemas.py

```
class PersonIn(ModelSchema):

    class Config:
        model = Person
        model_fields = ["first_name", "last_name"]
```

I want to have simple create/read api e.g.
api.py

```
def create_person(request, payload: PersonIn):
   data = payload.dict()
   try:
        person, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(**data)
    except Exception:
        return { "mesg": "Some error happened"}
```

What I wanted was to ensure that First Name and Last names are capitalized, before storing in DB.
I found that one method is to override Model method .save

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.first_name = self.first_name.capitalize()
       self.last_name = self.last_name.capitalize()
       super().save(self, *args, **args)
```

But, in this case update_or_create always creates a new object as it first checks for lower case fields and never finds it.

I also found that one can overwrite .clean method

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 
    def clean(self):
       self.first_name = self.first_name.capitalize()
       self.last_name = self.last_name.capitalize()
```

In this caseI understand I need to call .clean method manually. But that makes api way more complicated, that I assumed it would be. Also now it has taken that constraint of ensuring Capitalize words away from the Model. So, if someone now create a new version and do not ensure this, it will cause effectively duplicate entries e.g. "John Doe" and 'john doe".

```
def create_person(request, payload: PersonIn):
    data = payload.dict()

    #create object
    p = Person(**data)
    # clean /update fields
    p.clean()
     #but now it has extra fields

    d = {k: p.__dict__[k] for k in data}
   
    try:
        person, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(**d)
    except Exception:
        return { "mesg": "Some error happened"}
```

Question, how and where is such kind of contraints are usually implemented ?
e.g. I would like to avoid implementing this in Form fields in an interactive form and in an API as I mentioned above.

If I also update update_create, then I am again implemeting this constraint twice, isn't it ?

Comment: Why can't you just do `Person.objects.update_or_create(first_name=data['first_name'].capitalize(), last_name=data['last_name'].capitalize())` ?

Comment: Maybe i was not clear earlier. idea was to push that constaint to the model. This check, I beleive I mentioned earlier relies on the user to check that. Ior someone else might use that same object somewhere else, but may not do this check and thus failing the purpose. In other ways, I was looking for a way to put a constraint implement are model level and do not rely on the user who would use this model. So, as using a Form based updates or APi based updates do not need these kind of check implemented separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea might be to just make a dedicated field for this, like:

```
# app_name/fields.py


class CapitalizedCharField(models.CharField):
    # …
    def capitalize(self, txt):
        return txt.capitalize()

    def to_python(self, value):
        value = super().to_python(value)
        if value is not None:
            return self.capitalize(value)
        return value
```

Then you can plug this into the model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = CapitalizedCharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = CapitalizedCharField(max_length=100)
```

The advantage is that for filtering, it will also first capitalize, so:

```
Person.objects.filter(first_name='foo')
```

will capitalize the `'foo'` and thus search for `'Foo'` in the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this helps with that purpose. I was looking at creting custom field by exploring overriding pre_save method. But that did not help with querying and also for some reason returning capitalized value in pre_save was adding 2 rows in DB. This one does what I needed..